# Mac daemon application LSUIElement app shows in dock when open browser

Tags: java

so I am trying to make a hidden daemon application for Mac. I have the LSUIElement in the plist for the jar and it does hide the application from the dock until I open a browser window using `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(u);` When I do that, the application shows in the dock and stays there. Does anyone know how I can fix this?